# HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile path's format is not supported

Tags: asp.net, file, save

exception in ASP.NET "The given file format is not supported", in 
`HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile`, below is my code

```
string DocumentPath = "D:/Live//web/";

Path.Combine(DocumentPath, FileName);

HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + FileName);
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(DocumentPath);
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
response.Write(DocumentPath);
```

Comment: so, you gave the path, what's the file format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to insert also the file name.

Try this-

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(DocumentPath+ FileName);
```

**Update**

Try this lines of code

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="test.xls");
```

Instead of this-

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + FileName);
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
```

**Update 2**

The short answer is you **can't** save file on the computer of the client from security reasons.
So what you can do is only this line

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+fileName);
```

Without the `DocumentPath`.

**Last update**

```
//write file to the server
    string lines = "First line.\r\nSecond line.\r\nThird line.";
            System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("test.txt");
          file.WriteLine(lines);

      file.Close();
//read the file from server
      string david = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");
```

Comment: I did it but still its giving error like "Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Live\web\'."

Comment: What is the value of DocumentPath+ FileName? Are you sure this path is valid? it should looks like D:\Live\web\david.txt

Comment: Value of DocumentPath+ FileName is "D:/Live/web/Tax_5/18/2016 11:18:52 AM.xls", but the result is "The given path's format is not supported".

Comment: Try to change the name of the file to simple name without spaces and check what happen.

Comment: i did it by simple file named as "Tax.xls", but this time it is : "Could not find file 'D:\Live\\web\Tax.xls'." my requirement is to save Tax.xls file in D:\Live\\web\ path

Comment: ok, but first thing you can see there is a problem with file name with spaces.

Comment: Of course, but what can i do to save the file in preferred path as above.

Comment: What that line is use for? response.Write(DocumentPath); (the last lin)

Comment: i've removed that ln and done the code as you suggested above but the error is on the line: HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(DocumentPath + "\\"+ FileName);

Comment: I thought about it, and you are trying to save a file from web site response to some folder on the client server. I don't think this is possible from security reasons. you can save file on your server folder or just to send the client the file as response, but the client will decide where to save it.

Comment: Ok, actually my requirement is to create a excel file on the fly and save it into client location and mail the same file. These 3 steps has to be done in method.

Comment: So I don't think you can save on client's path location... only the client can choose where he want to save the file when it popup in the browser

Comment: Yes, i've done as you said above i've already done that, but i'm trying to create and save the file on the fly. Thank you.

Comment: without the documentPath? only simple file name like text.xls?

Comment: without documentpath i've exported the file and saved it in client location after popup fired with document

Comment: that is good i don't have any problem with that, but as i said i'm trying to create and save the file on the fly. Isn't it possible?

Comment: What that mean on the fly? to create file and then send it as attached file into email? You can create file on **your** server and do with it whatever you want. But not with response.

Comment: Yes, to create file and then send it as attached file into email.  Can't we send the same file in attachment after creating, to send in mail?